# React Native - ScrollView height changes after keyboard open/close with animation

Tags: javascript, react-native, animation, scrollview, jsx

I animate my view up `120` pixels when the keyboard opens for a `Modal` I have. When the keyboard closes, the view returns `120` pixels down. The problem is, the area that goes off screen at the top, when it gets animated back, the view is slightly smaller, and it gets slightly smaller each time, Here is the code - I will put a comment to show the view that is shrinking:

```
<Animated.View
        style={{
          paddingTop: 5,
          paddingBottom: 10,
          paddingLeft: 10,
          paddingRight: 10,
          marginTop: this.state.yPosition,
          marginBottom: this.state.yPositionPositive,
          flex: 1,
          marginLeft: (Dimensions.get('window').width - 300) / 4,
          backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.8)',
          width: 300,
          borderRadius: 4,
          borderWidth: 0,
        }}>
        <View style={{ flexDirection: 'column', justifyContent: 'space-between', flex: 1 }}>
          <View style={{height: 126, backgroundColor: 'blue', alignItems: 'stretch'}}>
            <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={{flexGrow:1}} style={{flexDirection: 'column', backgroundColor: '#e6fffe'}}>
              <View style={{height: 90, backgroundColor: 'red', flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', paddingTop: 5, paddingBottom: 5, borderBottomColor: '#6de3dc', borderBottomWidth: 0}}>
                <View style={{justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', flex: 0.5}}>
                  <View style={{flexDirection: 'column', justifyContent: 'space-between'}}>
                    <Image
                      source={require('../assets/billythekid2.jpg')}
                      style={{height: 60, width: 60, marginTop: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 10 : 10, borderColor: '#6de3dc', borderWidth: 2, borderRadius: 30}}
                    />
                    <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', marginTop: 5}}>
                      <Ionicons
                        name='ios-star'
                        color='#eec400'
                        size={14}
                      />
                      <Ionicons
                        name='ios-star'
                        color='#eec400'
                        size={14}
                      />
                      <Ionicons
                        name='ios-star'
                        color='#eec400'
                        size={14}
                      />
                      <Ionicons
                        name='ios-star'
                        color='#eec400'
                        size={14}
                      />
                      <Ionicons
                        name='ios-star'
                        color='#eec400'
                        size={14}
                      />
                    </View>
                  </View>
                </View>
                <View style={{flexDirection: 'column', backgroundColor: '#e6fffe', marginTop: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 10 : 10, flex: 0.5}}>
                  <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', flex: 0.5}}>
                    <View style={{flex: 0, alignSelf: 'center'}}>
                      <Text style={{fontSize: 16, fontWeight: '700'}}>
                        eamon.white
                      </Text>
                    </View>
                  </View>
                </View>
              </View>
              <View style={{flex: 0, marginBottom: 5, backgroundColor: '#e6fffe'}}>
                <Text
                  style={{
                    width: 280,
                    flex: 0,
                    backgroundColor: '#e6fffe',
                    paddingLeft: 5,
                    borderWidth: 0,
                    borderRadius: 4,
                    color: '#000',
                    fontSize: 14,
                  }}>
                    {this.state.messageFromSender}
                </Text>
              </View>
            </ScrollView>
          </View>
          <View style={{flex: 1}} onLayout={(event) => {
            this.setState({height: event.nativeEvent.layout.height});
          }}>
            <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={Keyboard.dismiss}>
              <View style={{ flexDirection: 'column', flex: 1 }}>
                <Text
                  style={{
                    flex: 0,
                    width: Dimensions.get('window').width,
                    color: 'white',
                    fontWeight: '700',
                    marginTop: 5,
                    marginBottom: 5
                  }}>
                  Date(s) Needed:
                </Text>
                {this.showCalendar()}
              </View>
            </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
            <View style={{ flex: 0, marginBottom: 10, justifyContent: 'center', flexDirection: 'column', marginTop: 0 }}>
              <TextInput
                style={{
                  width: 280,
                  borderColor: 'gray',
                  borderWidth: 1,
                  backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
                  paddingLeft: 5,
                  borderRadius: 4,
                  height: this.state.height - 313
                }}
                onChangeText={text => this.setState({ message: text })}
                value={this.state.message}
                multiline={true}
                numberOfLines={2}
                onFocus={this.animateUp}
                placeholder='Type a message...'
              />
            </View>
          </View>
          <View style={{ flex: 0.1, borderRadius: 4, borderWidth: 0, marginBottom: 10 }}>
            <TouchableOpacity
              activeOpacity={1}
              style={{
                backgroundColor: this.state.rentButtonBackground,
                flex: 1,
                justifyContent: 'center',
                alignItems: 'center',
                width: 280,
                borderRadius: 4,
                borderWidth: 0,
              }}
              onPress={() => {

              }}>
              <Text
                style={{
                  backgroundColor: this.state.rentButtonBackground,
                  textAlign: 'center',
                  color: 'white',
                  fontWeight: '900',
                  fontSize: 18,
                  borderRadius: 4,
                  borderWidth: 0,
                }}>
                RESPOND
              </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
          <View style={{ flex: 0.1, borderRadius: 4, borderWidth: 0, marginBottom: 10 }}>
            <TouchableOpacity
              activeOpacity={1}
              style={{
                backgroundColor: this.state.rentButtonBackground,
                flex: 1,
                justifyContent: 'center',
                alignItems: 'center',
                width: 280,
                borderRadius: 4,
                borderWidth: 0,
              }}
              onPress={() => {

              }}>
              <Text
                style={{
                  backgroundColor: this.state.rentButtonBackground,
                  textAlign: 'center',
                  color: 'white',
                  fontWeight: '900',
                  fontSize: 18,
                  borderRadius: 4,
                  borderWidth: 0,
                }}>
                ACCEPT
              </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
          <View style={{ flex: 0.1, borderRadius: 4, borderWidth: 0 }}>
            <TouchableOpacity
              activeOpacity={1}
              style={{
                backgroundColor: this.state.rentButtonBackground,
                flex: 1,
                justifyContent: 'center',
                alignItems: 'center',
                width: 280,
                borderRadius: 4,
                borderWidth: 0,
              }}
              onPress={() => {

              }}>
              <Text
                style={{
                  backgroundColor: this.state.rentButtonBackground,
                  textAlign: 'center',
                  color: 'white',
                  fontWeight: '900',
                  fontSize: 18,
                  borderRadius: 4,
                  borderWidth: 0,
                }}>
                DECLINE
              </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        </View>
</Animated.View>
```

Animations:

```
animateUp = () => {

    Animated.parallel([
      Animated.timing(this.state.yPosition, {
          toValue: -120,
          duration: 300,
      }),

      Animated.timing(this.state.yPositionPositive, {
          toValue: 120,
          duration: 300,
      })
    ]).start();
}
```

---

```
Animated.parallel([

    Animated.timing(this.state.yPosition, {
          toValue: 0,
          duration: 1,
    }),

    Animated.timing(this.state.yPositionPositive, {
          toValue: 0,
          duration: 1,
        })
]).start()
```

It starts out like this:

[image]

Each time the keyboard opens and closes, and the animation happens, pushing the top of the modal off the screen, the ScrollView shrinks a little - until it ends up looking like this:

[image]

Any suggestions would be great.

Comment: does removing animation help?

Comment: I figured out a solution, it was something with the animation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to animate a view when the keyboard opens, use `KeyboardAvoidingView`:

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/keyboardavoidingview